# Using Saver but IllegalArgumentException on EditableUserInputState cannot be saved using the current SaveableStateRegistry

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

There is an error here which goes the app into a crash:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: androidx.compose.samples.crane.base.EditableUserInputState@8b752c5 cannot be saved using the current SaveableStateRegistry. The default implementation only supports types that can be stored inside the Bundle. Please consider implementing a custom Saver for this class and pass it to rememberSaveable().
```

While I'm using a saver like this:

```
@Composable
fun rememberEditableUserInputState(hint: String): EditableUserInputState =
    rememberSaveable(hint, EditableUserInputState.Saver) {
        EditableUserInputState(hint, hint)
    }

class EditableUserInputState(private val hint: String, initialText: String) {
    var text by mutableStateOf(initialText)
    val isHint: Boolean
        get() = text == hint

    companion object {
        val Saver: Saver<EditableUserInputState, *> = listSaver(
            save = { listOf(it.hint, it.text) },
            restore = {
                EditableUserInputState(
                    hint = it[0],
                    initialText = it[1],
                )
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Where did I go wrong?

This code is a part of [compose codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-advanced-state-side-effects) but I write it to practice the code lab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer. All it needs is naming the argument not to have misvalued the function:

```
@Composable
fun rememberEditableUserInputState(hint: String): EditableUserInputState =
    rememberSaveable(hint, saver = EditableUserInputState.Saver) {
        EditableUserInputState(hint, hint)
    }
```

By putting `saver =` the error is resolved.